# Explode tab and get the tab in the next line

Tags: php

basically I have a text document that has the following content

```
136 998831511
137 1109901576
138 1233322632
139 1370468109
140 1522864163
141 1692206658
142 1880380039
143 2089478300
144 2321828287
145 2580015593
146 2866913327
147 3185714089
148 3539965496
```

The first column (#136-148) are player levels, the second column is the experience point the player needs before they can move to the next level

What I am trying to do is create a function that if I for example choose the level "140" and the player has the experience of the player that is level 136 **998831511** then it will check the players level in the text file and the exp it is supposed to have **1522864163** and update the players exp to be between the exp of the level 140 and the exp of the level 141.

This is the function I have created

```
function ExpIsBugged($CurrentLv,$CurrentExp)
{
    $File = @file('charlv.txt');


    foreach($File as $key => $FileLine)
    {
        $Lvs = explode("\t", $FileLine);


        $NewLv = $key + 1;

            if($Lvs[0] == $NewLv)
                $NewExp = $Lvs[1];

            if($Lvs[0] == $CurrentLv)
            {
                if($CurrentExp > $Lvs[1] && $CurrentExp < $NewExp )
                {

                    return "Your Exp Is Bugged";
                }
                else
                    return "Your Exp Is Not Bugged";
            }

    }
}
```

But I am getting the error "The variable $NewExp is undefined" and it will not get the exp of the next level.

Any Help?

Comment: `if($Lvs[0] == $NewLv)` you left out an equal sign.

Comment: `$NewExp` is only being set in an `if` that is missing a `=` - `if($Lvs[0] == $NewLv)`.

Comment: I fixed it, but still undefined variable.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what your function is trying to check? It wasn't clear to me with the explanation you gave.

Comment: Basically, some players exp are bugged. They are bugged by showing a value that is less than the exp they are supposed to have. For example a bugged character level 136 should have 998831511 exp, but they would have less than that. What i am trying to do is check if their exp is less than the level they are supposed to have then it will check the exp the level is supposed to have, and the exp of the next level, and update the characters exp to be in the middle of them

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
change this line in your code. it work fine

```
$Lvs = explode(0x09, $FileLine);
```

it give you 3 or 2 array(depend in your file);

```
$Lvs[0]= 136 //(lvl);
$Lvs[1]= " "
$Lvs[2] =998831511// (exp)
```

if it give you 2 array:

```
$Lvs[0]= 136 //(lvl);
$Lvs[1] =998831511// (exp)
```